# How do I indent a paragraph that wraps around a floating image?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to create a question and answer page, with indented answers. I have an image floating on the left at the top of the page. What I want to do is this:
[Indented Answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GesbU.gif)

Here is my HTML so far:

```html
<h2 align="center">Candidate Questionnaire</h2>
<a href="https://d3n8a8pro7vhmx.cloudfront.net/rogersparkfoodcoop/pages/161/attachments/original/1453726298/Anthony_Boatman_Square.jpg?1453726298">
  <img style="float: left; border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom: 1px; margin-left: 6px; margin-right: 6px;" src="https://d3n8a8pro7vhmx.cloudfront.net/rogersparkfoodcoop/pages/161/attachments/original/1453726298/Anthony_Boatman_Square.jpg?1453726298"
  alt="Anthony Boatman" width="150" height="150" />
</a>
<h3>Anthony Boatman</h3>
<h4>Why do you want to serve on the Board of Directors for the RPFC?</h4>
<p style="margin-left: 25px">I believe that food is becoming more and more a major concern. Here is some more sample text. Here is some more sample text. Here is some more sample text. Here is some more sample text. Here is some more sample text. Here is some more sample text. Here is some more sample text. Here is some more sample text. Here is some more sample text. Here is some more sample text. Here is some more sample text.</p>
```

but the paragraph's left edge is at the left edge of the page rather than the right edge of the image. If I indent by more than the width of the image, then the paragraph won't wrap properly. Is there a way to indent the whole paragraph that indents in relation to the image and page? I'd like to create a paragraph class `p.answers` with the indentation in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can just wrap your Question-Answer in a div and apply following css.

```
.answers {
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
}
```

Please refer following Jsfidle.

```
 https://jsfiddle.net/Rukhsana/fek24ag1/
```

Comment: Rukhasana Mulani,
Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I looked at your jsfiddle, and the result is not exactly what I am looking for. I'm trying to indent the entire answer paragraph relative to the question, and have both wrap around the photo.

Comment: I've created a new jsfiddle that does most of what I want. The issue is that the answer to the right of the photo is not indented, because the indent is measured from the left page margin and not the photos.
https://jsfiddle.net/swordams/ffuttmu4/1/

Answer (score 1):

Add `padding` to paragraph.

```
 p{
   padding-left: 140px;
 }
```

It will be easy to edit if instead of inline-style you use the following CSS between the `head` tags as embedded-style:

```
img {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black; 
  margin-top: 1px; 
  margin-bottom: 1px; 
  margin-left: 6px; 
  margin-right: 6px;
  }

p {
   padding-left: 140px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting a bit, I found a solution: give the tag you want to indent the attributes `display: table` and `padding-left: 10px`